# Keep the values of an html checkbox list on post without Webforms or Usercontrols

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to find a way to keep the values of a pure html checkbox list after a form submission in C#/ASP.NET, without the use of Webforms or Usercontrols. After the user submits the form and the page has reloaded, all the checkboxes should keep the same values.

Is this possible? Here is my code in it's simplest form:

```
<form method="post" runat="server">
    <label for="checkbox1">Checkbox 1
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox" runat="server" />
    </label>
    <label for="checkbox2">Checkbox 2
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox" runat="server" />
    </label>
    <label for="checkbox3">Checkbox 3
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="checkbox" runat="server" />
    </label>
    <label for="checkbox4">Checkbox 4
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" name="checkbox" runat="server" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This code is on html page or aspx page?

Comment: hey Irfan, it's on an aspx page.

Comment: You can do it by using server side and client side mix code. If you need help with the code let me know.

Comment: What you have posted here does exactly what you want: after a submission, the checkboxes do keep their values. So if they don't do that on your own webpage, there must be something interfering.